# Java - Saving to an internet file

Tags: java, file, save

I have a program with the capacity for multiple users.
At the moment the program is saving all the user details to file locally as a sting, then reading all the details back in and putting them back into an array.

I am wanting to save these details online so the program could be used from another computer, and i was wondering if there is a website that allows me to just save text files so they could be saved to, and easily read back in from the website.

Any help is much appreciated, or any ideas for a better solution would also be welcome!

Comment: Have you tried using databases?

Comment: What difference using database make? The database should be still stored on a server to be able to access from another computer

Comment: just save text files ... on pastebin.com with API

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS Of course the database still has to be on a server, but, at least with a database you can more accurately/effortlessly keep track of your data. Writing your save data for multiple users to a text file does not seem like a suitable way to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing anything slightly serious, I recommend buying a cheap web hosting. It costs less than 5$/month for GB's of disk space and 99.99% uptime is guaranteed.

If you use pastebin or someting similar all files will be exposed to the whole world.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution would be to use an FTP server to place the file. Your application could then pull down the file from the FTP server as needed and push it back up as well.

Of course, as others have suggested in the comments to your question, a more robust solution would be to use a database and have the "multi user application" be a web application, but that's a bit more involved than just pushing and pulling a file. (even if existing libraries and frameworks do make putting together a web application amazingly easy)

Answer (score 0):

`http://wrttn.me/46a604/` But I don't know how stable it is. Here is another one: `http://tinypaste.com/api/doc/`

I'm using notepad.cc more often but seems they don't have a API.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [pastebin API](http://pastebin.com/api) or API of some similar service. Use such service if you don't care about privacy of user's data.